# Disabling iPhone keyboard when selecting an HTML textarea

Tags: objective-c, css, iphone

I am trying to disable the iPhone keyboard for only some of the textAreas in an HTML document.  This document is displayed in a `UIWebView`.  I have tried the CSS webkit tags such as: `-webkit-user-select:none;` `-webkit-touch-callout:none;` `-webkit-user-modify:none;`. I have also tried the readonly property, but it does not suppress the keyboard, either.  Is there any way to disable the keyboard for only certian text areas?  I think users of my app will find it frustrating that the keyboard is popping up at inappropriate times.

Answer (score 1):

do you use html for this? if yes you can use the [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12) attribute `<textarea name="mytextarea" cols="2" rows="2" disabled></textarea>`